# Angular 15: Custom decorators on Properties not working

Tags: angular, angular-decorator

I follow e.g. [Angular Handbook](https://angular-book.dev/ch03-08-decorators.html) and define

```
export function LogClass(constructor: Function) {
    console.error('LogClass decorator executed for the constructor:');
    console.log(constructor);
}
```

and on my class

```
@Component({
   selector: ...
   templateUrl: ...
})
@LogClass    
export class MyCardComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
...
```

But somehow I never see any kind of `console` output. This should also work according the [Typescript manual](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html). Anything I miss for using an own decorator?

UPDATE:

After trying around I think the sample is not a valid one. I guess that the statements are called just once and are not called every time the class is created as new  instance - which is the main target I want to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your LogClass decorator below.

You can refer to this example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-decorators-example-2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: To some extend this looks promising but to some extend I cannot use it. Major blocking is that I cannot use `any`.  But anyway thx for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned sample was valid in Angular 14 and previous versions. Currently, the any class decorated by Angular decorators cannot use custom decorators. Related and confirmed https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/48276